# DB Error: syntax error when using custom profile to inut a new contact

Tags: profile, tags, lts

I'm running CiviCRM LTS (4.6.31) on Drupal 7.56 and a MySQL DB.

i built a custom profile to simplify Contactcreation. Each time i add my custom tags to that form i get the DB Error: syntax error when saving a new contact. It'sstil created though.
Contactcreation using der builtin form is working fine (even when setting tags)

This is the error from the drupla log:

```
$Fatal error details = ARRAY ( [callback] => ARRAY ( [0] => crm_core_error [1] => handle ) [code] => -2 [message] => db error: syntax error [MODE] => 16 [debug_info] =>
                              SELECT    contact_a.id                                           AS contact_id,
                                        contact_a.gender_id                                    AS `gender_id`,
                                        contact_a.first_name                                   AS `first_name`,
                                        contact_a.last_name                                    AS `last_name`,
                                        civicrm_note.id                                        AS note_id,
                                        civicrm_note.note                                      AS `note`,
                                        `1-location_type`.id                                   AS `1-location_type_id`,
                                        `1-location_type`.name                                 AS `1-location_type`,
                                        `1-email`.id                                           AS `1-email_id`,
                                        `1-email`.email                                        AS `1-email`,
                                        `1-phone`.id                                           AS `1-phone_id`,
                                        IF ( `1-phone`.is_primary = 1, `1-phone`.phone, NULL ) AS `1-phone`,
                                        `1-address`.id                                         AS `1-address_id`,
                                        `1-address`.state_province_id                          AS `1-state_province_id`,
                                        `1-address`.street_address                             AS `1-street_address`,
                                        `1-address`.postal_code                                AS `1-postal_code`,
                                        `1-address`.city                                       AS `1-city`,
                                        `website--url`.id                                      AS `website--url_id`,
                                        `website--url`.url                                     AS `website--url`,
                                        `website--url`.website_type_id                         AS `website--website_type_id`
                              FROM      civicrm_contact contact_a
                              left join civicrm_address `1-address`
                              ON        (
                                                  `1-address`.contact_id = contact_a.id
                                                  AND `1-address`.is_primary = 1 )
                              left join civicrm_email `1-email`
                              ON        contact_a.id = `1-email`.contact_id
                                        AND `1-email`.is_primary = 1
                              left join civicrm_phone `1-phone`
                              ON        contact_a.id = `1-phone`.contact_id
                              left join civicrm_location_type `1-location_type`
                              ON        ( (
                                                            `1-email`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id )
                                                  OR (
                                                            `1-phone`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id )
                                                  OR (
                                                            `1-address`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id ) )
                              left join civicrm_note
                              ON        (
                                                  civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact'
                                                  AND contact_a.id = civicrm_note.entity_id )
                              left join civicrm_website `website--url`
                              ON        (
                                                  `website--url`.contact_id = contact_a.id
                                                  AND `website--url`.website_type_id = )
                              WHERE     (
                                                  contact_a.id = '2968' )
                                        AND (
                                                  contact_a.is_deleted = 0 )
                              ORDER BY  `contact_a`.`sort_name` ASC,
                                        `contact_a`.`id` [nativecode = 1064 ** you have an error IN your SQL syntax;CHECK the MANUAL that corresponds TO your mysql server version FOR the right syntax TO USE near ') WHERE ( contact_a.id = '2968' ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) ORDER BY ' AT line 7] [TYPE] => db_error [user_info] =>
                            SELECT    contact_a.id                                           AS contact_id,
                                      contact_a.gender_id                                    AS `gender_id`,
                                      contact_a.first_name                                   AS `first_name`,
                                      contact_a.last_name                                    AS `last_name`,
                                      civicrm_note.id                                        AS note_id,
                                      civicrm_note.note                                      AS `note`,
                                      `1-location_type`.id                                   AS `1-location_type_id`,
                                      `1-location_type`.name                                 AS `1-location_type`,
                                      `1-email`.id                                           AS `1-email_id`,
                                      `1-email`.email                                        AS `1-email`,
                                      `1-phone`.id                                           AS `1-phone_id`,
                                      IF ( `1-phone`.is_primary = 1, `1-phone`.phone, NULL ) AS `1-phone`,
                                      `1-address`.id                                         AS `1-address_id`,
                                      `1-address`.state_province_id                          AS `1-state_province_id`,
                                      `1-address`.street_address                             AS `1-street_address`,
                                      `1-address`.postal_code                                AS `1-postal_code`,
                                      `1-address`.city                                       AS `1-city`,
                                      `website--url`.id                                      AS `website--url_id`,
                                      `website--url`.url                                     AS `website--url`,
                                      `website--url`.website_type_id                         AS `website--website_type_id`
                            FROM      civicrm_contact contact_a
                            left join civicrm_address `1-address`
                            ON        (
                                                `1-address`.contact_id = contact_a.id
                                                AND `1-address`.is_primary = 1 )
                            left join civicrm_email `1-email`
                            ON        contact_a.id = `1-email`.contact_id
                                      AND `1-email`.is_primary = 1
                            left join civicrm_phone `1-phone`
                            ON        contact_a.id = `1-phone`.contact_id
                            left join civicrm_location_type `1-location_type`
                            ON        ( (
                                                          `1-email`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id )
                                                OR (
                                                          `1-phone`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id )
                                                OR (
                                                          `1-address`.location_type_id = `1-location_type`.id ) )
                            left join civicrm_note
                            ON        (
                                                civicrm_note.entity_table = 'civicrm_contact'
                                                AND contact_a.id = civicrm_note.entity_id )
                            left join civicrm_website `website--url`
                            ON        (
                                                `website--url`.contact_id = contact_a.id
                                                AND `website--url`.website_type_id = )
                            WHERE     (
                                                contact_a.id = '2968' )
                                      AND (
                                                contact_a.is_deleted = 0 )
                            ORDER BY  `contact_a`.`sort_name` ASC,
                                      `contact_a`.`id` [nativecode = 1064 ** you have an error IN your SQL syntax;CHECK the MANUAL that corresponds TO your mysql server version FOR the right syntax TO USE near ') WHERE ( contact_a.id = '2968' ) AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) ORDER BY ' AT line 7] [to_string] => [db_error: MESSAGE = "DB Error: syntax error" code = -2 MODE = callback callback = crm_core_error::handle prefix = "" info = "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.gender_id as `gender_id`, contact_a.first_name as `first_name`, contact_a.last_name as `last_name`, civicrm_note.id as note_id, civicrm_note.note as `note`, `1 - location_type`.id as `1 - location_type_id`, `1 - location_type`.name as `1 - location_type`, `1 - email`.id as `1 - email_id`, `1 - email`.email as `1 - email`, `1 - phone`.id as `1 - phone_id`, IF (`1 - phone`.is_primary = 1, `1 - phone`.phone, NULL) as `1 - phone`, `1 - address`.id as `1 - address_id`, `1 - address`.state_province_id as `1 - state_province_id`, `1 - address`.street_address as `1 - street_address`, `1 - address`.postal_code as `1 - postal_code`, `1 - address`.city as `1 - city`, `website--url`.id as `website--url_id`, `website--url`.url as `website--url`, `website--url`.website_type_id as `website--website_type_id` FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_address `1-address` ON (`1-address`.contact_id = contact_a.id AND `1-address`.is_primary = 1) LEFT JOIN civicrm_email `1-emai] )
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test against the latest release (4.7.24) - it is likely fixed there

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to an incorrect `website` join in the query. Is there any `website field` in your custom profile?

If yes, you can try disabling/deleting it and check if you still find an issue.

You can also raise a bug in [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/) with some info of replicating the same.

Comment: thx, disabling the website field fixed the error!